# Dynamodb date between query not working on GSI key

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a users table, where the Partition Key is only `ID` and I added a GSI on `createdDate`. The format of `createdDate` is `YYYY-MM-DD`. I have 2 requirements, `get` the user only by ID & `query` the users by the date range. Both queries are separate.

Now `get` by ID works. When I try to `query` by exact date on `createdDate` field, it works, but when I change the query to add a `BETWEEN` clause, it fails with following error:

```
Error ValidationException: Query key condition not supported
    at Request.extractError (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/aws-dynamo-local/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: 2022-07-25T04:35:59.155Z,
  requestId: '084b79e7-40a9-4012-915c-aaa073885db0',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 9.402842709895587
}
```

My query:

```
const params = {
  TableName: "users",
  IndexName: "startDate-index",
  KeyConditionExpression: "startDate between :start AND :end",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":start": { S: "2021-09-22" },
    ":end": { S: "2024-09-22" },
  },
};
```

Table meta:

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "startDate",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "TableName": "bookings",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
    {
      "IndexName": "startDate-index",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "startDate",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `Query` you specify the PK value and an SK range. You're trying to specify a PK range. You need to construct a GSI which has the ranged value in the SK. For example, by putting the year-month as the PK.

At scale this isn't a fantastic design because you're creating yourself a hot key, especially on writes, but it's fine for lower scale apps where you're pushing fewer than 1,000 WCUs to the same PK.

Comment: My PK is `ID, I have a GSI on `createdDate`, and I am trying to put a date range on it(not on PK) which is not working, so whats wrong in my approach, I am not able to understand your answer.

Comment: You cannot do a range constraint (BETWEEN) on a partition key. Partitions work kinda like hash tables. You’ll notice you also can’t ask a hash table to delete all keys in a range. The hash table would just look at you funny. 

You can do ranges on sort keys. So you must design a data model that puts the thing you want to range against into a sort key (all under the same PK).